# UPSERT in PostgreSQL using jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq, upsert

I am trying to perform an UPSERT in PostgreSQL using the jOOQ library.

For doing this I am currently trying to implement the following SQL statement in jOOQ:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6527838

My code looks like this so far:

```
public class UpsertExecutor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UpsertExecutor.class);

    private final JOOQContextProvider jooqProvider;

    @Inject
    public UpsertExecutor(JOOQContextProvider jooqProvider) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(jooqProvider);

        this.jooqProvider = jooqProvider;
    }

    @Transactional
    public <T extends Record> void executeUpsert(Table<T> table, Condition condition, Map<? extends Field<?>, ?> recordValues) {
        /*
         * All of this is for trying to do an UPSERT on PostgreSQL. See:
         * https://stackoverflow.com/a/6527838
         */

        SelectConditionStep<Record1<Integer>> notExistsSelect = jooqProvider.getDSLContext().selectOne().from(table).where(condition);
        SelectConditionStep<Record> insertIntoSelect = jooqProvider.getDSLContext().select(recordValues).whereNotExists(notExistsSelect);

        try {
            int[] result = jooqProvider.getDSLContext().batch(
                jooqProvider.getDSLContext().update(table).set(recordValues).where(condition),
                jooqProvider.getDSLContext().insertInto(table).select(insertIntoSelect)
            ).execute();

            long rowsAffectedTotal = 0;
            for (int rowsAffected : result) {
                rowsAffectedTotal += rowsAffected;
            }

            if (rowsAffectedTotal != 1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Upsert must only affect 1 row. Affected: " + rowsAffectedTotal + ". Table: " + table + ". Condition: " + condition);
            }
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof BatchUpdateException) {
                BatchUpdateException cause = (BatchUpdateException)e.getCause();

                logger.error("Batch update error in upsert.", cause.getNextException());
            }

            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

This code does however not compile, since select() doesn't support a map of values:

```
SelectConditionStep<Record> insertIntoSelect = jooqProvider.getDSLContext().select(recordValues).whereNotExists(notExistsSelect);
```

### The Question

How do I provide select() with a set of predefined values like this: `SELECT 3, 'C', 'Z'`?

### Update 1

I managed to get the code working. Here is the complete class:

```
public class UpsertExecutor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UpsertExecutor.class);

    private final JOOQContextProvider jooqProvider;

    @Inject
    public UpsertExecutor(JOOQContextProvider jooqProvider) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(jooqProvider);

        this.jooqProvider = jooqProvider;
    }

    @Transactional
    public <T extends Record> void executeUpsert(Table<T> table, Condition condition, List<FieldValue<Field<?>, ?>> recordValues) {
        /*
         * All of this is for trying to do an UPSERT on PostgreSQL. See:
         * https://stackoverflow.com/a/6527838
         */

        Map<Field<?>, Object> recordValuesMap = new HashMap<Field<?>, Object>();
        for (FieldValue<Field<?>, ?> entry : recordValues) {
            recordValuesMap.put(entry.getFieldName(), entry.getFieldValue());
        }

        List<Param<?>> params = new LinkedList<Param<?>>();
        for (FieldValue<Field<?>, ?> entry : recordValues) {
            params.add(val(entry.getFieldValue()));
        }

        List<Field<?>> fields = new LinkedList<Field<?>>();
        for (FieldValue<Field<?>, ?> entry : recordValues) {
            fields.add(entry.getFieldName());
        }

        SelectConditionStep<Record1<Integer>> notExistsSelect = jooqProvider.getDSLContext().selectOne().from(table).where(condition);
        SelectConditionStep<Record> insertIntoSelect = jooqProvider.getDSLContext().select(params).whereNotExists(notExistsSelect);

        try {
            int[] result = jooqProvider.getDSLContext().batch(
                jooqProvider.getDSLContext().update(table).set(recordValuesMap).where(condition),
                jooqProvider.getDSLContext().insertInto(table, fields).select(insertIntoSelect)
            ).execute();

            long rowsAffectedTotal = 0;
            for (int rowsAffected : result) {
                rowsAffectedTotal += rowsAffected;
            }

            if (rowsAffectedTotal != 1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Upsert must only affect 1 row. Affected: " + rowsAffectedTotal + ". Table: " + table + ". Condition: " + condition);
            }
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof BatchUpdateException) {
                BatchUpdateException cause = (BatchUpdateException)e.getCause();

                logger.error("Batch update error in upsert.", cause.getNextException());
            }

            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

It does however not feel very clean with the `List<FieldValue<Field<?>, ?>> recordValues` parameter. Any better ideas on how to do this?

Comment: It seems the val() static method might be what I'm looking for: http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class%29

Comment: You know you'll have to use `SERIALIZABLE` transactions in a retry loop, or lock the table, for that to work reliably, right?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, I am aware of that. Can you recommend a better approach? I am very interested in better solutions to this problem.

Comment: sql `select 3,'C','Z';` is much the same as sql `values (3,'C','Z');` , so yes `val()`  sounds like the right method.

Comment: FYI PosgreSQL 9.5 will have UPSERT. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT

Answer (score 26, accepted):

jOOQ 3.7+ supports PostgreSQL 9.5's `ON CONFLICT` clause:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4299
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

The full PostgreSQL vendor-specific syntax is not yet supported, but you can use the MySQL or H2 syntax, which can both be emulated using PostgreSQL's `ON CONFLICT`:

#### MySQL `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .insertInto(TABLE)
   .columns(ID, A, B)
   .values(1, "a", "b")
   .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
   .set(A, "a")
   .set(B, "b")
   .execute();
```

#### H2 `MERGE INTO ..`

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .mergeInto(TABLE, A, B, C)
   .values(1, "a", "b")
   .execute();
```

Comment: Utility derived from Lucas' solution for TableRecord objects:

```public static int upsert(final DSLContext dslContext, final UpdatableRecord record) {
        return dslContext.insertInto(record.getTable()).set(record).onDuplicateKeyUpdate().set(record).execute();
    }```

Comment: @ud3sh: Hey, thanks for mentioning. Feel free to provide this as a full answer. I'm sure it might be useful for others!

Answer (score 24):

Here is an upsert utility method derived from Lucas' solution above for UpdatableRecord objects:

```
public static int upsert(final DSLContext dslContext, final UpdatableRecord record) {
    return dslContext.insertInto(record.getTable())
                     .set(record)
                     .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                     .set(record)
                     .execute();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with PostrgreSQL (or actually H2 in PostgreSQL mode)

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by @ud3sh comment with JOOQ 3.11, Kotlin, and the PostgreSQL DSL

This is an extension function to call `upsert` directly on the `UpdatableRecord` object

```
import org.jooq.UpdatableRecord

internal fun UpdatableRecord<*>.upsert(): Int {
    if(this.configuration() == null) {
        throw NullPointerException("Attach configuration to record before calling upsert")
    }
    return this.configuration().dsl().insertInto(this.getTable()).set(this).onConflict().doUpdate().set(this).execute()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems a bit of a complicated way of achieving the objective. Why not use a simple stored fucntion? how to create an upsert function is described in the  [postgresql manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) then just call it from your java code.

Comment: +1. The only correct way to implement upsert now (until 9.5 released) is to use stored function with cycle as written in given link. More information is here http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/