# How to insert record into database using spring jpa when there is no conflict

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have spring boot application that is connected with the PostgreSQL database using `spring-data-jpa`, here is my entity with nearly 40 fields

Now for saving the entity into database, I'm just using the `studentRepository.save` method

```
studentRepository.save(new StudentEntity());
```

**DAO Entity**

```
  @Table
  @Entity
  public class StudentEntity {

     @Id
     @Generate( using database sequenece)
     private long studentId;

     private String studentName;

     private String dept;

     private String age;
      ..
      ..
      }
```

**Repository**

```
 public interface StudentRepository implements JPARepository<Long, Student> {
   }
```

But now I have requirement, if there is any student record in table with `name` and `dept` I should not insert the new record, I know I can use PostgreSQL `ON CONFLICT` with native query for this, but if I use native query I have to specify all 40 fields in query and as method arguments which looks ugly.

Is there any way to make it simpler?

**Example of native query**

```
@Query(value = "insert into Users (name, age, email, status) values (:name, :age, :email, :status)", nativeQuery = true)

 void insertUser(@Param("name") String name, @Param("age") Integer age, @Param("status") Integer status, @Param("email") String email);
```

Comment: Declare a unique index on those attributes, insert unconditionally, and catch/translate a thrown exception?

Comment: I'm not sure sir about what you are explaining @chrylis

Comment: We had faced a similar issue where I had to use the "ON DUPLICATE KEY" feature specific to MYSQL database. Initially we went ahead with using @Query initially, but was not readable. So we searched and found [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) to be a suitable alternative for such cases.

Comment: can you show an example for the above scenario, and how to integrate that one?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35083965/11189140

Comment: if I understand but still I have to provide all 40 values in that query ?

Comment: yeah, but instead of setting these variables in an object, you set it inside the jooq query generator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the database. Create a [unique constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) on the 2 fields and trying to add multiple of those will be prevented.

Something like

```
ALTER TABLE StudentEntity ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_NAME_DEPT UNIQUE (studentName,dept);
```

This unique constraint will prevent the insertion of duplicate combinations.

You could also define an constraint on your JPA entity to automatically create the index for testing

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"studentName", "dept"})
```

Comment: I will try this thank you, does it throws any exception while inserting duplicate records? or will just ignore?

Comment: In the case of exception spring will take care of closing connection part right? as a programmer do we need to do anything other than handling it?

Comment: I strongly suggest you readup on the technologies you are using (JPA and Spring). No you don't need to do anything (if you use thins in a normal way!). Also you can just use the `save` method on the repository, you don't need a seperate insert method for that nor a dedicated query.

Comment: The one downside of the unique constraint approach (as opposed to `insert... on conflict do nothing`) is that Hibernate with log the collision as an error. So depending on how often this happens, it may or may not be worth the noise to you. (Yes, you could configure your logger to ignore error messages from Hibernate's SqlExceptionHelper class, but that could hide other real errors).

Comment: The constraint works out-of-the-box. The `insert .. on conflict do nothing` requires a custom query to be written and doesn't work on all databases.

Answer (score 0):

If your priority is to reduce verbosity, as it is native sql you can avoid the names of the fields if you put them in the correct order, but you must put all the values of the table, even the null:

```
@Query(value = "insert into Users values (:name, :age, :email, :status)", nativeQuery = true)
 void insertUser(@Param("name") String name, @Param("age") Integer age, @Param("status") Integer status, @Param("email") String email);
```

Or instead of doing it with native insert, you can save if the method  findByStudentNameAndDebt(studentName, dept), does not return any result. In StudentRepository (here native is not necessary):

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Student as a WHERE lower(a.studentName) = lower(:studentName) AND lower(a.dept) = lower(:dept)")
    public Student findByStudentNameAndDebt(@Param("studentName") final String studentName, @Param("dept") final String dept);
```

And in your service:

```
if(studentRepository.findByStudentNameAndDebt(studentName, dept)==null) {
   studentRepository.save(new StudentEntity());
}
```

Comment: This is not thread safe. Imagine if two threads started at the same time: both would get `null` from `findByStudentNameAndDebt` and then both would save new entity.

Answer (score 0):

No need of native query. You can do it by writing object oriented queries too. first check is there any record present in table by `name` and `dept`.
If it returns null, then do your save.

## StudentRepository.java

```
public interface StudentRepository implements JPARepository<Long, Student> {


@Query("FROM Student AS stu WHERE lower(stu.name) = lower(:studentName) AND lower(stu.dept) = lower(:dept)")
public Student findStudentByNameAndDept(@Param("studentName") String studentName, @Param("dept") String dept);

//if you have already duplicates in your db, then you can do the followings too..
@Query("FROM Student AS stu WHERE lower(stu.name) = lower(:studentName) AND lower(stu.dept) = lower(:dept)")
public List<Student> findAllStudentsByNameAndDept(@Param("studentName") String studentName, @Param("dept") String dept);
```

}

## StudentService.java

```
if(studentRepository.findStudentByNameAndDept(name,dept)==null){
    //save
}else{
    //custom hanlding
    throw StudentExistsException("Student with the given name/dept exists");
}

OR
//if already duplicates exisited in db

if(studentRepository.findStudentByNameAndDept(name,dept).isEmpty()){
    //save
}else{
    //custom hanlding
    throw StudentExistsException("Student with the given name/dept exists");
}
```

Comment: This allows race conditions to happen, when two threads have passed the if condition and entered into the save block at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a lightweight query to check whether a student with same name and department already exists

```
public interface StudentRepository implements JPARepository<Long, Student> {

@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(c) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM Student s WHERE s.studentName= :studentName AND s.dept= :dept")
    public boolean existsByNameAndDepartment(@Param("studentName") String studentName, @Param("dept") String dept);
```